# In SSMS Running SQL which doesn't return rows with go between statements gives an error

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2017-express

I am using SSMS v17.6 with a SQL Server Express v14.0.1000.169.

When I run the following `DELETE` statement:

```
delete from foo
go
```

I get the error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'go'.

But if I execute a similar `SELECT` statement:

```
select * from foo 
go
```

Then there is no error.

It seems the error happens with any statement that doesn't return results. I have checked the query execution settings in SSMS and the batch separator is set to go. It seems SSMS is sending to the server which it shouldn't do.

**I have seen this on multiple machines.**

Comment: Good question +1.  I wonder if all DML statements would behave this way.  In any case, though semicolon is part of the ANSI-92 standard, it wasn't fully adopted by SQL Server, hence it seems it has its own quirky set of rules.

Comment: Hm... seems to be version specific since I couldn't reproduce the error - neither in SSMS nor in SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/09ab8/1 ...

Comment: Interestingly every example given here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql is terminated even though the terminator is supposedly optional ([]).

Comment: I can't repro this on any version of SSMS. Perhaps there are non-displayable characters in your first script. Do you get the error if you type the delete script from scratch into a new query window?

Comment: Dan Guzman is probably right. I've seen this before. Usually it's because of carriage return/line feed characters hanging out after a copy and paste. It's insanely irritating. Start with a new, clean tab and type, don't paste, your query.

Answer (score 0):

I would be curious to know if this was the only script in the batch? I suspect a character somewhere prior to the code you're running is causing the problem.

There are two ways to validate this:

1. Open a new tab in SSMS, enter `delete from foo go` and execute.
2. Add a terminator prior to the statement `;delete from foo go`.

In those circumstances does the error still occur?

Answer (score 0):

> Take the GO out. It's not a T-SQL statement, it's a management studio
>   batch breaker.

The `GO keyword is not T-SQL`, but a SQL Server Management Studio artifact that allows you to separate the execution of a script file in multiple batches.I.e. when you run a T-SQL script file in SSMS, the statements are run in batches separated by the `GO` keyword.

Check this Link [SQL Server Utilities Statements - GO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go?view=sql-server-2017) for more details.

If you read that, you'll see that sqlcmd and osql do also support GO.
SQL Server doesn't understand the GO keyword.

> So if you need to DELETE table better to use WHERE Condition, the
>   WHERE clause specifies which record(s) should be deleted. If you omit
>   the WHERE clause, all records in the table will be deleted.

Basic DELETE Syntax:

```
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE condition;
```